# How do blood substitute increase the risk of stroke?

Tags: medications, hematology

When describing blood substitute's (BS's) made of perfluorocarbons use in clinical trials, one of the most commonly described side effected in the increase risk of stroke in the area were the PFC is being injected.

How do they increase the risk of stroke? In addition, is the increase risk of risk that overwhelming to prevent its adoption use? There are several examples of drugs, such as hormonal or pain relievers/narcotics that increase risk of clotting/stroke, but these are widely sold. BS's are for emergency use, so the usage of the former drugs seems but not the latter seems puzzling.

Comment: Medical Sciences has a requirement for prior research before this can be migrated. You say "one of the most commonly described side effected in the increase risk of stroke" so why not provide a reference? If "hormonal or pain relievers/narcotics that increase risk of clotting/stroke, but these are widely sold" why not mention some of them and provide information about the rates these side effects occur with those examples?

Comment: References going to be added ASAP. Thank you

Comment: You say they increase the risk of stroke "in the area [where] the PFC is being injected." The only place a stroke occurs is in the brain, so what do you mean by this? Did you you actually mean blood clots rather than stroke?